# How to add single quote “ ' ”at beginning and end of field?

Tags: notepad++, text-editor

I need to add a single quote at the begining and end at field in NotePad++.

EX:

```
MLOS-032,MLOS-104,MLOS-159,MLOS-189,MLOS-267,MLOS-270,MLOS-315,MLOS-333
```

Desired result:

```
'MLOS-032','MLOS-104','MLOS-159','MLOS-189','MLOS-267','MLOS-270','MLOS-315','MLOS-333'
```

Comment: Replace , with ', '  then add ' at beginning of line and its end

Comment: Thanks Praveen. It works exactly what i need !

Answer (score 15):

you can use expreg like this:
replace ^(.*)$ with '\1'

[image: Look at the image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, I want to add I used it but in the Replace with I added a comma that way separate each row with a comma: Find what: ^(.*)$ and Replace with: '\1',

Answer (score 8):

If all fields are ALWAYS containing alphanum and dash, you can do:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find what: `([\w-]+)`
Replace with: `'$1'`

Then click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

`([\w-]+)` is a character class that matches alphanumeric character (including underscore) and dash.
This will replace each field by the same with single quotes arround it.

Comment: Change `"$1"` to `'$1'` and you've got it.

Comment: @Kennah: Good catch! Thank you.

Comment: flawless answer

Answer (score 6):

Use the replace function. Check the Checkbox named `Regular expressions`.

Then replace ^ (beginning of the line) with single quote.
$ (end of the line) with single quote.
and , with ','.

This three replacemants should do the Job.